# How to extend the `getter`-functionality of SQLAlchemy's association_proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, sqlalchemy

**Edit:** I would like to model a `1 to 0:1` relationship between `User` and `Comment` (a User can have zero or one Comment). Instead of accessing the object `Comment` I would rather directly access the comment itself. Using SQLAlchemys `association_proxy` works perfect for that scenario **except** for one thing: accessing `User.comment` before having a `Comment` associated. But in this case I would rather expect `None` instead of `AttributeError` as result.

Look at the following example:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text, ForeignKey, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(Text)

  def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

  # proxy the 'comment' attribute from the 'comment_object' relationship
  comment = association_proxy('comment_object', 'comment')


class Comment(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'comments'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  comment = Column('comment', Text, nullable=False, default="")
  user_id = Column(ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False, unique=True)
  # user_id has to be unique to ensure that a User can not have more than one comments

  def __init__(self, comment):
      self.comment = comment

  user_object = orm.relationship(
      "User",
      uselist=False, # added after edditing the question
      backref=orm.backref('comment_object', uselist=False)
      )

if __name__ == "__main__":
  engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
  Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
  Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  session = Session()
```

Now, the following code throws an `AttributeError`:

```
u = User(name="Max Mueller")
print u.comment
```

What would be the best way to catch that exception and provide a default value instead (like an empty string)?

Comment: Maybe one solution would be to provide a specific `getset_factory`-parameter calling the `association_proxy`. But how?

Comment: Is this really a `1-to-1` relationship (User can have only one Comment, as implied by your model)?

Comment: It looks to me that you should move the `uselist=False` outside of `backref` definition so that it applies to the `user_object` side of the relationship. Then you should rename the `comment` to `comments` and it will be a collection instead of a scalar object, so there should not be any exception.

Comment: Maybe I gave a bad example but I am looking for a general solution for a `1-to-0:1` relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really *need* `association_proxy` for this.  You could really get by just fine with a regular `property`.  The `AttributeError` is (probably) caused because the comment_object is itself `None`, since there is no dependent row, and `None` has no `comment` attribute.

```
class User(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(Text)

  def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

  # proxy the 'comment' attribute from the 'comment_object' relationship
  @property
  def comment(self):
      if self.comment_object is None:
          return ""
      else:
          return self.comment_object.comment

  @comment.setter
  def comment(self, value):
      if self.comment_object is None:
          self.comment_object = Comment()
      self.comment_object.comment = value
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text, ForeignKey, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(Text)

  def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

  # proxy the 'comment' attribute from the 'comment_object' relationship
  comment = association_proxy('comment_object', 'comment')


class Comment(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'comments'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  comment = Column('comment', Text, nullable=False, default="")
  user_id = Column(ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)

  def __init__(self, comment):
      self.comment = comment

  user_object = orm.relationship(
      "User",
      backref=orm.backref('comment_object'),
      uselist=False
      )

if __name__ == "__main__":
  engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
  Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
  Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  session = Session()
  u = User(name="Max Mueller")
# comment = Comment("")
# comment.user_object = u

# session.add(u)
# session.commit()
  print "SS :", u
  print u.comment
```

You gave `uselist` in `backref` which must be in `relationship`.

Comment: I would like to model a `1-to-0:1` relationship (now, I claryfied that in the question). Therefore, `uselist=False` should be bi-directional which I added also in the question.

Comment: with the help of backref you can access User.comment_object.

Comment: The association_proxy operates on `User.comment_object`. Shouldn't it work also for `uselist=False` with respect to `comment_object`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any answer that would solve the issue and also would work with  "sort_by" for example.

Maybe it is just better to use 'column_property", see [Order by association proxy: invalid sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389436/order-by-association-proxy-invalid-sql).