# Association_proxy with 0-n relations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got an error trying to use an association_proxy.

I got mapped class A, with 0-n relation to B. B has 0-n relation to C. The association_proxy is to access A from C.

```
class C(base):
    a = association_proxy('b', 'a')
```

It works without problem if it *really* has a relation to B. But if this relation is `null`, then trying to access myCinstance.a throws a: `AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'`.
I guess it works well with 1-n relation, but is there a way that myCinstance.a returns `None` instead of an error? (I saw the creator option, but looks to be only for setting, not getting).

Thanks in advance.

I’m using SqlAlchemy 0.7.5

**EDIT**: I came up with a simple example describing the problem https://gist.github.com/2225046

Comment: is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063478/how-to-extend-the-getter-functionality-of-sqlalchemys-association-proxy ?

Comment: It will work for one of my use case ( access myCinstance.a ). But I wouldn’t be able to filter query like `.query(C).filter(C.a==…)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe from reading http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#querying-with-association-proxies that the case is handled when you are issuing a query (ie the SQL uses an EXISTS clause to catch the non existing B issue).

In order to get the accessor shortcut to work, you need to use the getset_factory argument:

```
def outer_join_accessor_factory(collection_type, proxy):
    def getter(obj):
        if obj is None:
            return None
        return getattr(obj, proxy.value_attr)
    def setter(obj, value):
        setattr(obj, proxy.value_attr, value)
    return getter, setter

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_b = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'))
    b = relationship('B', backref='cs')
    a = association_proxy('b', 'a', getset_factory=outer_join_accessor_factory)
```

Comment: Also a great example for the getset_factory, as the SQLAlchemy lacks this part.