# Order by association proxy: invalid sql

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to attach a column of a related model to another model and use it like any other sqlalchemy column attribute. As mentioned in [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html), association_proxy makes it easy to use.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from app import db


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(...)
    name = db.Column(...)

class Book(db.Model):
    author_id = db.Column(...)
    author = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[author_id])
    author_name = association_proxy('author', 'name')
```

But when I call `Book.query.order_by(Book.author_name.asc()).all()` I got this:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "ASC"
LINE 4: ...user.id = book.author_id AND user.name ASC)
```

Sqlalchemy generates EXISTS statement:

```
...
EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM user
WHERE user.id = book.author_id AND user.name ASC)
```

So how to use ordering properly with an associated attribute?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is probably best to use a [`column_property`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property):

```
Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)    
    name = Column(Unicode())


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    author_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    author = relationship('User')


Book.author_name = column_property(select([User.name]).where(User.id == Book.author_id))


# sample ORM query
books = session.query(Book).order_by(Book.author_name)
```

Comment: This select statement returns all users with existing books and I get this error: `(psycopg2.errors.CardinalityViolation) more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`. Is there any way to filter by specific Book object id?

Comment: Which select statement? I have updated the example with a sample query.

Comment: I mean select in column_property. Something like this:
`
SELECT user.name
FROM user, book
WHERE user.id = book.id

produces: 1. Name1, 2. Name2, ...
`

Comment: I believe the example now works correctly. Do you get any error messages?